# Android caching properties file in memory to avoid I/O

Tags: java, android, file, caching, properties

I have an android project with a properties file store in assets folder. My need is to avoid possibly I/O reading for that file every time a value is needed, for ex loading the file the first time and keep it in a static field. Keep in mind that this is an application "always running" in an embedded tablet so basically there is no lifecycle. This is an implementation i made for this:

Properties.java:

```
private static java.util.Properties properties;
private static Context mContext;

public static void init(Context context) {
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    if(properties == null){
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStreamReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("path_to_prop_file"), "UTF-8");
            properties = new java.util.Properties();
            properties.load(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static String get(String entry){
    try {
        return properties.getProperty(entry);
    } catch (Exception e){
        init(mContext);
        return properties.getProperty(entry);
    }
}
```

then i call it from Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Properties.init(getApplicationContext());
    String property = Properties.get("prop_key");
}
```

i'm caching also context in case the properties file need to be reloaded. I could pass context as a param to "Get" method but i need properties to be read everywhere in the app and i don't want to pass context through all the classes. 
I'm wondering if this implementation is ok and if the leak about the context is dangerous in my case. 
Any suggestion are appreciated

EDIT 1: finally block added to close the reader as suggested

Comment: consider closing your reader in a finally block

Comment: @NicolasFilotto sure i will thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the leak about the context is dangerous in my case

In terms of the leaks, the `Application` is a global singleton. It is pre-leaked; you cannot leak it further. Your `Properties` is leaked, but that is by design.

> I'm wondering if this implementation is ok

You have not addressed threading. Having this kind of I/O on the main application thread will lead to dropped frames and UI jank. And, once you start to get into threading, your implementation will get a lot more complex to deal with race conditions (e.g., code wants to use a property before the thread reading the properties has completed executing).

I'd revisit the idea of packaging the properties file in the first place. For example, you could:

- Hand-write a Java class containing those properties
- Add a bit of code to your `build.gradle` file that converts those properties into fields on the `BuildConfig` class, using `buildConfigField`
- Write a small code-generating Gradle plugin that converts your properties into a Java class ([this book sample of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/Staticizer) does this for a simple JSON file)

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for your reply! If i understood, every call to the java.util.Properties.getProperty(String) method is an I/O read to the Properties file? I thought it was only the InputStream that does the I/O once. I will look also for the Gradle solution to covert prop into java class

Comment: @Nem3sis: "I thought it was only the InputStream that does the I/O once" -- correct. My assumption is that you are using your `get()` method on the main application thread. If that is always going to be called on some background thread, so you are not blocking the main application thread with your `init()` I/O ever, then my threading concerns fall away.

Comment: yes i use `get()` on main thread. I will make analysis in dropped frames and consider moving in backgroud if the case. Thanks